# A better way to count and sort by frequency?

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I have a string `liste` like this

```
title1;duration1
title2;duration2
title1;duration3
```

Which means that the `title` was shown for `duration` milliseconds to be replaced by the next `title` for the next `duration`.

`title` can repeat itself.

The goal is to look for each `title` that is the same, to then add its `duration` to then create a list of all distinct `title`s sorted descendingly by their sum of `duration`s.

My approach:

```
string[] units = liste.split('\n');
Dictionary<string, long> d = new Dictionary<string, long>();
foreach(var row in units)
{
  string[] e = row.split(';');
  //if e[0] in d => add e[1] to d[e[0]] else set d[e[0]] to e[1]
}
//Convert d to list and sort descendingly by long.
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You are using the correct datastructure for this, I think if performance problem arrive it will be because of string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not necessarily suggesting this is the best way because it is kind of incomprehensible and maintainable code is important, but you can obtain your result in a single statement with LINQ. This solution assumes you have confidence in your data being clean - meaning no blank values or values that don't convert to double, etc.

1. split the string on newline
2. project an object for each line and substring at ";"
3. Group by title
4. project again into a new list that sums the groupings
5. Finally sort the list.

```
string liste = @"title1;8.91
    title2; 3
    title1; 4.5";
    
var result = liste.Split('\n')
    .Select(l => new {
        title = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf(';')).Trim(), 
        duration = l.Substring(l.IndexOf(';')+1, l.Length - (l.IndexOf(';')+1)).Trim()
    })
    .GroupBy(l => l.title)
    .Select(l => new { title = l.Key,  durations = l.Sum(m => double.Parse(m.duration))})
    .OrderByDescending(l => l.durations);
```

Comment: How do you keep track when constructing this linq? Also, try to change it for exceptions to be catchable without having to do an all-or-nothing try catch around it. Yes I did read "This solution assumes you have confidence in your data being clean", but this is hard to deliver.

Comment: You could break it out into multiple steps. Like step one might be create a list of title/duration pairs and throw out any that do not validate per whatever rules you decide. Once you have a clean list start at the GroupBy step.

Answer (score 0):

Use linq :

```
           string input = "title1;10\n" +
                           "title2;20\n" +
                           "title1;30";
            var rows = input.Split(new char[] {'\n'}).Select(x => x.Split(new char[] {';'})).Select(y => new {title = y.First(), duration = int.Parse(y.Last())}).ToList();
            var sums = rows.GroupBy(x=> x.title).Select(x => new {title = x.Key, duration = x.Sum(y => y.duration)}).ToList();
```